# text between any tag

Tags: c#, xml

```
<name>Tag 6</name>
```

using XmlTextReader how can i read the value of the  text between the name tag
.ie how can i get **Tag 6**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (reader.Read()){
   if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "name"){                               
       this.tagXml.Append("<").Append(reader.Name).Append(">");
       currentTag = reader.Name.Trim();
       //first loop go through this
   }                   
   if(reader.NodeType== XmlNodeType.Text){
      //second loop go through this
      if (currentTag == "name"){
        this.tagXml.Append(reader.Value);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You might want to annotate what your doing in each of those blocks. it seems unnecessary and doesn't look like it answers your question. you seem to be missing context. what is 'this' and 'tagXml'?  by your question it looks like this should just return the  'reader.Value' in the second block to get 'Tag 6' as per your question

Answer (score 3):

With *ReadElementString* function:

```
var text = string.Empty;
using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(filename))
{
    reader.MoveToContent();
    text = reader.ReadElementString(); // read content text from current node
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: After doing this. reader is not reading any closing element why :(

Comment: @user444569:  xml (or html) elements consist of a starttag, attributes, contents and an endtag, there is no 'closing element', so i think you mean an endtag.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs I'm guessing you need to do something like

ReadToDescendant
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayf5ffy5.aspx

to find the name node.

then

ReadInnerXml to get the content.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readinnerxml.aspx

not used it though